# Content of unmatched string

Tags: regex, perl, io

I am parsing input from stdin, which is in the following format:

```
1
2
3
done
```

My current code is:

```
while(<> =~ /(\d+)/) {
    # do something with $1
}
# I want to access the line following the last number here
```

which is fine for the 1st part of the file (with the list of numbers).
However, I would like the content of the line immediately following the last number.

Is there any elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
my $line;
while( ($line = <>) =~ /^(\d+)$/ ) {
  # do something with $1
}
chomp $line;
# Do something with $line (done)
```

As another answer states, it is a good idea to use `chomp` with a line of input. It will deal with the newline char or chars in a platform-independent way. If you use a regex to match the number, `$1` will be "clean".

Also as another answer states, `/(\d+)/` will match a number anywhere in the line. `/^(\d+)$/` will match a line that only contains a number.

Another way:

```
foreach my $line (<>) {
  if( $line =~ /^(\d+)$/ ) {
    # Do something with $1
  }
  else {
    chomp $line;
    # Do something with $line (done)
  }
}
```

This will let you deal with multiple or even alternating lines of numbers and other text.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    last if !/^\d+\z/;

    ... $_ ...
}

die("Premature EOF") if !defined($_);

... $_ ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
my $var = <>;
chomp $var;

while($var =~ /^(\d+)$/) 
{
    #here do stuff with $var, containing only numbers

    $var = <>;
    chomp $var;
}

# here do stuff with $var, containing now a word
```

other thing: by changing `/(\d+)/` for `/^(\d+)$/` you make sure your entry contains ONLY numbers ;)

Comment: why the downvote tho?
Please tell me if my answer is incorrect but honnestly i don't see what's wrong

Comment: Perhaps because it handles EOF poorly? But then again,Javier Elices's also suffers from that problem, and they didn't get downvoted, and mine doesn't suffer from that problem and it got silently downvoted too.